# How do you use json.dump to dump multiple arrays to one document?

Tags: python

I'm attempting to make an account creation software in which the user's 3 main details, their name, their random ID and password are all stored in a .txt document. The program runs fine however it can only store one array. Once I attempt to create a second account, it overwrites and deletes the first account. Is there any way to use `json.dump()` to write multiple arrays or do I need to use a different package?

```py
def accCreation():
    account = []
    fullName = input("What is your full name?: ").upper()
    print()
    uniqueID = random.randint(100000, 999999)
    print("Your unique, six digit ID, is:", uniqueID)
    print("Write this down!. You will need it later!")

    def passwordCreation():
        print()
        password = input("Please create a password: ")
        account = [fullName, uniqueID, password]
        with open('Cinema Login.txt', 'w') as login:
            json.dump(account, login)
            print("Account Created! Welcome!")
            menu()

    passwordCreation()
```

Comment: Create a list that contains all the lists you want to dump, then dump that list-of-lists

Comment: You're truncating the file each time with `'w'` so only one account will ever be there. Append to the file by using `'a'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're opening the file with the `w` flag which overwrites the file. To append to an existing file, use the `a` or `a+` flag

```py
   with open('Cinema Login.txt', 'a') as login:
       ...
```

See [this refernce page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fopen/)

Comment: This worked. I was unaware that the flags had different qualities. Thanks!

Comment: Note that, now you are appending to the file, you will get lots of lines, or `json` arrays in the file. You will now be unlikely to be able to read that file back using `json`.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read the `Cinema Login` file in full first, then update the accounts and write it all back:

```
def passwordCreation():
    print()
    password = input("Please create a password: ")
    account = [fullName, uniqueID, password]

    accounts = []
    try:
        with open('Cinema Login.txt', 'r') as login:
            accounts = json.load(login)
    except ValueError:
        pass

    accounts.append(account)
    with open('Cinema Login.txt', 'w') as login:
        json.dump(accounts, login)
        print("Account Created! Welcome!")
```